# Three Dimension Array Display Table

Tags: pascal

I know how the two dimensions array works in pascal, [rows, columns].

How the three or more dimensions works? Please help, thanks.

**a[rows, columns, ???]**

Comment: `a[rows,columns,planes]`  If this isn't what you were expecting as an answer you should explain a lot more clearly what you are expecting.

Comment: I want to make a loan table, is this the right assignment ?
  a[0, 0, 0] := 1000; // loan
  a[0, 1, 0] := 500; // down payment 1
  a[0, 1, 1] := 42; // kredit 12x
  a[0, 1, 2] := 21; // kredit 24x
  a[1, 0, 0] := 2000; // loan 2

Comment: The dimensions are all there. Even if we don't know what to call them. :)

Answer (score 0):

A one dimensional array is declared as `array[lowIndex..HighIndex] of <type>`, as in

```
intArray: array[0..9] of integer;
```

A two dimensional array is simply an array containing an array, as in:

```
twoDim: array[0..9,0..9] of integer;
```

You reference it using the indexes:

```
twoDim[0,0] := 1;
twoDim[0,1] := 2;
```

A three dimensional array simply extends the two dimensional, as in this declaration:

```
threeDim: array[0..9,0..9,0..9] of integer;
```

You also use it with the indexes, in the same way:

```
threeDim[0,0,0] := 1;
threeDim[9,0,1] := 12;
```

As far as what to call the individual dimensions, use names that mean something related to the purpose they serve. For instance, if I was keeping an array of hourly readings for something each day over the period of a week for four weeks, I could declare the array as:

```
Readings: array[1..4,1..7,1..24] of integer;
```

I could then declare variables to name the indexes:

```
var
  Week, Day, Hour; Integer;
```

I could then reference the three dimensions of the array easily. To initialize them all to zero, for instance, I could do something like this:

```
for Week := 1 to 4 do
  for Day := 1 to 7 do
    for Hour := 1 to 24 do
      Readings[Week, Day, Hour] := 0;
```